# Stop Ajax Flickering With If result changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flicker

I recently read on how to fix this and found a solution sort of but I need help applying the solution.

Here is my working code//This Has Flicker

```
$(function worker(){
    // don't cache ajax or content won't be fresh
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false,
        complete: function() {
          // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
          setTimeout(worker, 2000);
        }
    });

    var ajax_load = "";

    // load() functions
    var loadUrl = "https://test.com/updatedsales.php";

    $(".result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);

// end  
});
```

Here is anti flicker code solution that is not working where do I put solution?

```
if(json.status ==  "ACTIVE" && $('.result').html() !== "ACTIVE") {
    $('.result').html(jason.status);
}
```

So where do I put the above solution in my code provided? I am sorry for asking a question that might seem easy to JavaScript and jQuery pros. This has frustrated me and I really need some help from you guys. Thank you for reading this, James.

Comment: Hello mate, it's impossible to understand your question. Can you please provide a JSfiddle to demonstrate your code, and the thing you want and when you want?

Comment: That is not going to magically stop the flicker. You are going to get flicker when you keep replacing all the content and than loading it.....

Comment: How do I only do an ajax request if the result changed. Using the solution     if(json.status ==  "ACTIVE" && $('.result').html() !== "ACTIVE") {
    $('.result').html(jason.status);
}

Comment: Um, you have to call the server to see if it changes, that code does nothing.

Comment: So how would I ask the server if it changed?